# Prevent calling Worklight adapter from browser

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

For the security reason of my app.I have to prevent adapter access from the browser.And want to only access from mobile App.

Now when I invoke adapter from browser
https://xxx.xx.xx/invoke?procedure=login&adapter=xxadapter&parameters=["user","paas"]

got below response.

/*-secure- {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"i9k34qhnj7r25s8ab7v2m0sf3l"}}}*/

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention if you actually managed to get the correct response from the adapter call made in the browser. I'm guessing not.

You can protect the adapter with a security test that will trigger a challenge. If the issuer of the call was not the app itself that contains the logic to handle the challenge, the request done from the browser - which is unable to perform the challenge handling since it lacks the applicable logic (JS code) to do so, will fail.

Comment: Thanks Iadan for quick response.Actully i got correct response when i set securityTest='wl_unprotected' in procedure defination in xml file of adapter.And when i remove securityTest='wl_unprotected' then i got /-secure- {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"i9k34qhnj7r25s8ab7v2m0sf3l"}}}/                                                                            Is there any server configuration for production to handle this?

Comment: When not setting any security test, there are default security tests in place.

Comment: It sounds to me like everything is working as expected.